# Is it safe to make angularjs routing by id?

Tags: angularjs

I need to put a link into email. When user clicks on it, angularjs app should open specific page and entity. I suppose that the link should contain id of the entity. This allows to find the record on backend side and then open page.

Is it safe to publish such a link in email(I mean id of the record in DB)? Do we need to hash id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see much trouble.

There are a lot of web pages (angular or not) which provides direct links to pages using the entity id as parameter.

In the case of angular, when another - non-authorized - user tries to enter, it will ask the backend, the backend with reject its petition and you can redirect the user to the home page. So if some user tries to access that route, he well just see the home page.

It is also true that in general (I mean, not angular specifically) some people likes to hash the id, but I don't see that as really needed.

So it comes down to the use case / personal preference. From the point of security, your backend won't give any entity even if you know every piece of it. You need to be logged in AND able to retrieve it.